# MySQL DataBase design Question

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm thinking of the best way to design a database given the following situation.

- There are over 1000 hotel room units.
- Each hotel room unit has a list of about 100 individual types of items with a qty attached to them.  The inventory is standard for each hotel room. But the qty of each item can be changed.

For example 3 coffee mugs, 2 towels etc.

I also need to track lost or damaged items for each unit...

what would be the best way to design the database?

Have a table of each unique item, its qty, its property id, its lost and damaged items for each property ID?

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table of rooms
Table of items
Table of contains that references rooms and items:

```
Rooms
Number  ID
101     1
102     2

Items
Name    ID   NumberLost   NumberDamaged  
Lamp    1    3            0
Chair   2    0            1

Contains
RoomID  ItemID  Quantity
1       1       1
1       2       3
2       1       1
2       2       4
```

Comment: You can modify this to add extra information, but this should give you an idea of how to structure the relations.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
Room[roomID, roomNumber, roomSize]
Item[itemID, itemPrice, itemName]
RoomItem[roomID, itemID, quantity, damaged]
```

Have a many-to-many relation with room and items (called RoomItem). Can then be specific about the quantity for an item in a room and a damaged item in a room.

Comment: +1 especially for storing damaged quantity against RoomItem. (Should also include lost quantity.)